# Write the equation of a hyperbola in matrix form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices

I read online the following problem.

> A quadratic equation of the form $x^2 + 8xy + 7y^2=1$ represents a curve in the $x-y$ plane. Write this expression in matrix form.

I personally don't understand the sense in this, but it seems interesting. How would one go about describing this equation with matrices?

Comment: Let $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ Then with $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$ we have that your equation is exactly

$$\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x}=0.$$

Comment: How on earth did you come up with that? By the way, I'd be glad to have that comment (and subsequent responses) as an answer.

Comment: That is, if there was some logical motivation behind it other than a guess.

Comment: There was, I have mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$ and $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$ then your equation is the same as

$$\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x}=0.$$

This is the matrix form. It is a standard trick in the theory of quadratic forms, and a well-practiced means of dealing with them. Gauß himself actually used this version to classify quadratic forms up to equivalence. I'm not sure it's immediately obvious if you haven't seen it, but this is how it is traditionally taught in courses involving quadratic forms.

Comment: I mean I see how the matrix relates to the coefficients in the quadratic, but how would this work for other polynomials, such as cubic, quartic, ..., n-tic?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan it doesn't. This is a trick used for quadratic forms. You can do it with linear ones by doing $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}$, but the higher degree forms aren't studied with matrix methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've now read online many articles on this approach to quadratic forms.